# Select Element with Max Occurrence in Multiset

Tags: java, collections, guava

I may want to rephrase the question to "How do I select first item in a Multiset?" because it seems Multiset is already ordered according to frequencies.

I have a Multiset myList = Multiset.create();

```
[maa00 mfnt11 malignlft mbold mlt18 mfl x 3, caa00 cfnt11 calignlft cbold clt17 cfl]
```

I could not find any method like myList.getIndex(0). Please note, in the end, I need the count of element that has maximum frequency.

Is there any one liner for this ? Or do I have to do that iteration?

Update : 
I am getting maximum frequency using :

```
myList.count(Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myList).asList().get(0)));
```

But this is too slow. Can you please suggest, what exactly should I use?

Update 1: Using above copyHighestCountFirst method is proving too slow. In one instance of loop, it is taking 80+milliseconds opposed to average 40 milliseconds using without it. 
In large loops, should I prefer simple iteration?

Update 2 : Got it working using :

```
myList.count(myList.entrySet().iterator().next().getElement())
```

Without almost zero impact on performance. I still wonder if there is any better way to do it.

Sidenote : In Python I did the same with :

```
j = defaultdict(int)
for k in clList:
    j[k] +=1
result1 = max(j.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1]) //count of frequency of item with max count
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's been a lot of alternatives thrown around between your question and the other answer posted, but many of them seem to depend on the idea that `.get(0)` or `.iterator().next()` is going to get you the most frequent element. It will not!

Your only two decent choices are `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(bag).elementSet().iterator().next()`, which is wasteful as you say, or loop through the `entrySet` manually and check each to see if it's the most frequent so far.

You should file a Guava feature request to extract the most frequent element. I can't promise what will happen to it, but it's worth requesting.

Answer (score 5):

I was running into a similar challenge today in trying to find a simple, reasonably efficient way to find the element in a `Multiset` with the maximum count. In the future we live in with Java 8, I was able to modify Louis Wasserman's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745017/7988403) into a clean one liner:

`multiset.entrySet().stream().max(Ordering.natural().onResultOf(Multiset.Entry::getCount)).get();`

This will give you the `Multiset.Entry` with the maximum count (assuming `multiset` isn't empty) allowing you to access either the element or its count.

Answer (score 4):

One alternate solution that wouldn't require an explicit loop -- but would run in linear time in the number of distinct elements, which most of these other solutions can't -- would be

```
Ordering.natural().onResultOf(new Function<Multiset.Entry<Foo>, Integer>() {
  public Integer apply(Multiset.Entry<Foo> entry) {
    return entry.getCount();
  }
}.max(multiset.entrySet()).getElement();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of your edits and phrasing it's not clear what you want. Also, using `myList` as variable name which is a multiset isn't descriptive - I'll use `bag` as variable name for multiset (it is bag after all).

1. "*it seems Multiset is already ordered according to frequencies*" - is it or is it not ordered according to frequencies?

   ```
   ImmutableMultiset<String> bag = ImmutableMultiset.of(
       "c0ffee", "abba", "mfl", "mfl", "mfl", "c0ffee");
   ```

   is `[c0ffee x 2, abba, mfl x 3]` because it uses insertion order, so your collection **may** be ordered properly by coincidence (I don't know if it is a case here). If you're not sure about ordering, just use

   ```
    ImmutableMultiset<String> sortedBag = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(bag)
   ```

   which gives `[mfl x 3, c0ffee x 2, abba]`. Since `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst` returns immutable multiset, you don't have to use it in loop assuming your multiset doesn't change. If you just did a silly microbenchmark and saw that using `Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst` is twice as slow meaning 80 ms vs 40 ms - forget it because [*premature optimization is the root of all evil*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). I assume we have properly ordered `sortedBag` at this point.
2. From what I see you want **count of most common element in bag** which is simply:

   ```
   int count = sortedBag.entrySet().iterator().next().getCount();
   ```

   or if your multiset is `ImmutableMultiset`:

   ```
   int count = sortedBag.entrySet().asList().get(0).getCount();
   ```

   Note that `sortedBag.entrySet()` is a collection of [`Multiset.Entry`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.Entry.html) which has both element and count so pick one you want.
3. Having [`ImmutableMultiset`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultiset.html) allows you to use it's `ImmutableList` view on which you can call `get(0)` to fetch element:

   ```
   sortedBag.asList().get(0)
   ```

   which gives you only element (here: a string) without count, so if your plan is to fetch only element you can use `asList()` instead of playing with iterator.